# Vuex store state change doesn't update Vue views

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

(please apologise my english)

In the following code using Vue's single file component (es6), I don't understant why the view isn't updated as the state of the store change:

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import App from './components/App.vue'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    foo: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    foo (state) {
      state.foo++
    }
  }
})

Vue.use(Vuex)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  store
})
```

**components/App.vue**

```
<template>
<div @click="$store.commit('foo')">
  {{ $store.state.foo }}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {}
}
</script>
```

I can see in Vue Devtool that the state is well updated at every click, but the view only display `0`

Strange comportment: If I use the hot-reload tool and made some change to the template (adding `test:` before the `{{ $store.state.foo }}` for example), it cause the view to refresh itself (?) and display the right value... (but don't fix the reactivity issue)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you in advence for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

As I was formating my own code for this question, I tried to put the `Vue.use(Vuex)` before the `new Vuex.Store` and it solve the problem...

So **this will work**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store(...)
```

And **this wont**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const store = new Vuex.Store(...)
Vue.use(Vuex)
```

### Explaination

I faced this problem because I put the instanciation in another file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import store from 'my-store'

Vue.use(Vuex)
```

...and StandardJS deny me to import something in another place than the top of the file...
So **this trigger warnings**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

import store from 'my-store'
```

### Final solution

I solved this by moving the `import Vuex from 'vuex'` and the `Vue.use(Vuex)` in the other file so:

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from 'my-store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  store
})
```

**my-store**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({...})
```